# Cassandra and inserting float columns

Tags: java, cassandra

I have the following Cassandra configuration:

```
    <ColumnFamily CompareWith="LongType" Name="MiFamily">
```

But when I try to insert the following value:

```
    public byte[] dateToByte(Date date) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);  
        dos.writeLong(new Long(1).longValue());                      
        dos.flush();  
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        return data;        
    }
```

I get the following exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:A long is exactly 8 bytes)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.translate(ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.java:28)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl$1.execute(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:103)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl$1.execute(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:96)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(FailoverOperator.java:384)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.FailoverOperator.operateSingleIteration(FailoverOperator.java:190)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.FailoverOperator.operate(FailoverOperator.java:99)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl.operateWithFailover(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:151)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl.batchInsert(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:107)
    at borrar.PruebasCassandra.insertData(PruebasCassandra.java:77)
    at borrar.PruebasCassandra.main(PruebasCassandra.java:96)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:A long is exactly 8 bytes)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_insert_result.read(Cassandra.java:13332)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_insert(Cassandra.java:717)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_insert(Cassandra.java:692)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl$1.execute(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:100)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Off-topic, but: `dos.writeLong(new Long(1).longValue());`?! How 'bout `dos.writeLong(1L);`?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. The byte array has a length of 8 as expected. Are you sure this is the code which is causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. I was doing something wrong when using batchInsert.

Comment: Can you please explain what you were doing wrong and how you fixed it?  Others may be having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra 0.8.1 does support Float:

- Add Date, Float, Double, and Boolean types (CASSANDRA-2530)
- See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2530

Using Java Hector:

```
StringSerializer se = new StringSerializer();
FloatSerializer fls = new FloatSerializer();
mutator.insert("mykey", "User", HFactory.createColumn("ftest", 0.12345678f, se, fls));
```